# device-mapper error while setup of dm-cache

Tags: linux, cache, ssd, device-mapper

I am trying to setup dmcache using the tutorial https://wiki.mikejung.biz/Dmcache
When I run the command

```
`dmsetup create home-cached --table '0 976771120 cache /dev/mapper/ssd-metadata /dev/mapper/ssd-blocks /dev/sdc1 512 1 writeback default 0'`
```

I receive the below error response

```
device-mapper: reload ioctl on home-cached failed: No such device
```

Below is the output of dmesg

```
 [1305010.875406] device-mapper: table: 253:5: cache: Error opening origin device
    [1305010.875410] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table


Command failed
```

I also tried to follow the tutorial github.com/mingzhao/dm-cache

And ran the command

```
echo 0 131072 cache /dev/sda /dev/sdb 0 8 65536 256 1 | dmsetup create foo
```

I received the  error

```
device-mapper: reload ioctl on foo failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed
```

I am not able to understand dm-cache used in the first post and the dm-cache  by https://github.com/mingzhao/dm-cache are the same ? as the setup seems to be little different in both case.